# How can i check if a number is higher or lower then another number?

Tags: bash, calculator

I have files that contain 2 numbers like the following:

File 1

```
1
0
```

File 2

```
0
1
```

File 3

```
3
3
```

I want to compare the number on the first line to the number on the second line.
If the number on the first line is higher echo : `Higher`
If the number on the first line is lower echo : `Lower`
If the number on  both lines are the same echo : `Same`

How can i acheive this?

Comment: Hello!  What have you tried? How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: I have tried to use an if statement that checks using: echo "a=$a";
echo "b=$b";

if [ $a \> $b ]; however i am not sure how to set each number in the files to a and b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the files. For each file, read the two numbers, then compare them:

```sh
for file in file1 file2 file3; do
    { read num1; read num2; } <"$file"
    if [ "$num1" -gt "$num2" ]; then
        echo Higher
    elif [ "$num1" -lt "$num2" ]; then
        echo Lower
    else
        echo Same
    fi
done
```

Arithmetic comparison in the shell is done with `-gt` and `-lt`.  The other arithmetic comparison operators are `-ge`, `-le` and `-eq`.  See `man test`.  The operators `<` and `>` will test for lexicographical ordering, and will not be what you want to use here.

Or, with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='' -F '\n' '{ print ($1 > $2 ? "Higher" : ($1 < $2 ? "Lower" : "Same")) }' file1 file2 file3
```